# Android AlertDialog showing up blank

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an AlertDialog in onCreateView() inside a Fragment. Here's the code I'm using:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()));
builder.setTitle("blah blah blah");
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        //do something
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
});
builder.create().show();
```

But whenever this executes, I get a completely white dialog where nothing is visible. If I click around the box, I eventually find where the positive button is because the code in setPositiveButton's OnClickListener gets executed. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, the rest of my app is in the background and I'm left with a useless dialog box. I've tried changing the theme, but that hasn't made any difference. I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem, so any information as to why this is happening is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you show dialog before inflate your xml to fragment? and try getActivity instead of getContext.

Comment: @HemantParmar I inflate the xml for the fragment before I show the dialog. And I've tried both getContext and getActivity, but the result is the same.

Comment: show your dialog before inflate the XML to fragment.

Comment: @RyanKelsey this sounds like white text on a white background. I notice that in the obscured part of your screenshot you have white text on a dark background. Does this activity's theme set `textColorPrimary` to a white color, perhaps?

Comment: @RyanKelsey try to 

Import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog instead of android.app.AlertDialog

Comment: It actually not blank, just the text in white color, you need to create a custom style for alert dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertStyle);
```

Add in Style.xml file

```
<style name="AlertStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f3f3f3</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#f3f3f3</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I've tried using getActivity() and getContext(), but the same thing happens both times.

Comment: @RyanKelsey please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `create()` method from the `builder.create().show()` like that

```
builder.show();
```

Comment: I've tried both builder.show() and builder.create().show(), but the same thing happens both times.

Comment: @RyanKelsey Rebuild it again and then try it

Answer (score 0):

Try this for all version

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
else
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setTitle("title");
builder.setMessage("Message");
builder.create().show();
```